# How to change SQL data sources for a search application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

Currently I am working on an application that searches through an SQL table for voters registration information such as first name, last name, city, etc.

So far, I am only able to search through one table but I want to be able to give the user options to change which years they can search for.

How can I accomplish this?

This is my current code:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{public class VoterDataLayer
{
    public DataTable SelectSearch(string lastName, string firstName, string middleName, string nameSuffix, string city, string zip)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VoterReg"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spVR092011", Connection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", middleName);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameSuffix", nameSuffix);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", zip);

                Connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

 }
```

}

Stored procedure

```
USE [Voters]
```

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spVR092011]    Script Date: 1/15/2015 8:56:28 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spVR092011]

```
@LastName varchar(25),
@FirstName varchar(25),
@MiddleName varchar(25),
@NameSuffix varchar(4),
@City varchar(250),
@Zip varchar(10)
```

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT TOP 1000 [LastName] AS [Last Name], 
        [FirstName] AS [First Name],
        [MiddleName] AS [Middle], 
        [NameSuffix] AS [Suffix],
        [City],
        [Zip] AS [Zip Code],
        [RegistrantID]
FROM [dbo].[VR092011]
WHERE
        [LastName] LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%' AND
        [FirstName] LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND
        [MiddleName] LIKE '%' + @MiddleName + '%' AND
        [NameSuffix] LIKE '%' + @NameSuffix + '%' AND
        [City] LIKE '%' + @City + '%' AND
        [Zip] LIKE '%' + @Zip + '%'
```

END

Comment: Are you saying you have different "Years" of data in different tables? Also, note that `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` both implement `IDisposable` and as such should be explicitly closed or enclosed in a `using` statement

Comment: A description of the tables involved will be useful...

Comment: You are adding parameters to the existing cmd object.. why can't you add years to the parameters and default it to null on the database Stored procedure..? this does not see to be that difficult based on what you are explaining also `seby408` if you are not sure waht `stuartd` is saying.. you could do something like this if you are not sure how to wrap the fore mentioned objects in a `using(){}` `((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();` you can do the same for the `SqlAdapter Object` as well

Comment: Posting your `spVR092011` stored procedure would be helpful. As @MethodMan said, this seems like it's probably a trivial change to your current code.

Comment: @stuartd yes that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles It is just tables that have first name, last name, city, address etc. I want to be able to choose which years I want to search from. Each year has a different set.

Comment: `do you have a column named `Year or Years, or what ever the column name` that pertains to the field in question...? which doesn't look like you do so you will have to add the field.. or Join on some table that has the relationship to that field..

Answer (score 0):

Adding a parameter to your stored procedure to change which table the sproc selects from is going to force you to build your query as a string and execute with sp_executesql, since precompiled SQL must explicitly name a table.

This will work, but it's ugly. You have a couple of alternatives, but they are also ugly:

1. building your sql query on the client (swapping out the table name as needed) and passing to the server
2. Creating a separate stored procedure for each set of data and deciding which to call based on user input.

All of this ugliness stems from your suboptimal data structure. A properly normalized database would have data from all years in a single table, and a year column to allow filtering. If your data was structured this way, your solution would be as simple as passing in an additional parameter.